# How can I get Powershell to recognize a file name with a umlaut 'ä'?

Tags: powershell

I am running the following Powershell code:

```
$regFiles = @(
    'regs_10_2019-04-10-07_58_48_geän.csv'
)
$base = 'C:\Temp'

$regFiles | %{
    $f = "$base\Archive\$_"
    # vvv This throws an error because it cannot find the file with the 'ä'
    move-item -Path $f -Destination $base
}
```

If the file name has an 'ä' in it, it is not found by Powershell. Is there a way to get Powershell to recognize the file name?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have a problem with your script (in my German locale) executing in PowerShell console directly. What encoding did you save the script file with?

Comment: what happens if you use `-LiteralPath` instead of `-Path`?

Comment: work on my computer

Comment: Works here too (US locale) on Windows 10 Pro & using PS 5.1

Comment: Works on Dutch locale (Windows 7 Pro, PS 5.1). Are you absolutely sure a file with that name exists?

Comment: Does `Get-Item -Path 'C:\Temp\Archive\regs_*_geän.csv'` give you any result?

Comment: I saved the file as UTF-8, but I retried using 1252, and got the same result.

Comment: -LiteralPath produced the same result.

Comment: I can retrieve the file from the PS command prompt, but once I save it in the script, it doesn't work. I have tried UTF-8, UTF-8BOM, UTF-16LE, and 1252 as encodings.